Turbulence in flow of spacetime
Why is there no turbulence in the flow of spacetime around black holes? How does this flow differ from typical physical flows described by the Navier-Stokes equations with friction, or even the frictionless flows described by Euler and Bernoulli?

Spacetime doesn’t flow in general. It has no velocity in general nor does it have viscosity. So the concept of turbulence doesn’t apply in general.
There is a “river model” which only applies to static spherically symmetric spacetimes. This model does not generalize. In this model the geometry is so simple that there cannot be any turbulence.
